# Mysql selecting temporary table outside of the loop

Tags: mysql

```
BEGIN

    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_users LIKE users;
    SET @fact_id = FactId;

    SELECT count(*) INTO @CheckExists from users WHERE fact_id = @fact_id;
    WHILE(@CheckExists > 0)
    DO 
    INSERT temp_users SELECT * FROM users WHERE fact_id = @fact_id;

    SELECT fact_id into @fact_id FROM users WHERE fact_id = @fact_id;
    SELECT count(*) INTO @CheckExists from users WHERE fact_id = @fact_id;


    END WHILE;
    SELECT * FROM temp_users;

END
```

I don't understand why when I make the `SELECT * FROM temp_users;` outside of the loop I get an empty table, but if I make this query inside the while loop I can get some rows

Comment: Huh, wouldn't this cause an infinite loop?

Comment: no, because the code is executed well, but I get 0 rows, but If I put that select inside the while loop I can get 2 rows

Comment: 1. `SELECT fact_id into @fact_id FROM users WHERE fact_id = @fact_id;` - this line doesn't make any sense. What are you trying to accomplish?
2. I think Passerby is right, the way it is written will result in an infinite loop if the `count(*)` wields anything > 0

Comment: @user3350814 I'm not sure if I misread something or you misposted something, but it seems `$fact_id` will never change (`SELECT fact_id INTO @fact_id WHERE fact_id=@fact_id`).